# Idea of base change for Division algebras over local field

Tags: rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures, division-algebras

Let $F$ be a non-Archimedean local field of characteristic $0$ and $K/F$ be a finite extension. Let $D_F$ be the central division algebra of dimension $n^2$ over $F.$ Write $D_K=D_F\otimes_FK$, which is again a central division algebra over $K$ of dimension $n^2$. Does there exist an idea of base change for division algebra.

In case of $GL(n),$ the following diagram is commutative.

$$
\matrix{
  \widehat{W_F}     & \longrightarrow^{{}^{LLoc}}   &\widehat{ GL(n,F)} \cr                
  \downarrow^{res_{K/F}}&                 &  \downarrow^{BC_{K/F}}  \cr
 \widehat{W_K}  & \longrightarrow^{{}^{LLoc}}  & \widehat{GL(n,K)}                \cr
}
$$
where LLoc is Local Langlands correspondence, $res_{K/F}$ is restriction map and $BC_{K/F}$ is base change map.

Do we have similar diagram in  case of Division algebras. If yes, how the base change map look like ?

More generally,

$A_F$ be the finite central simple algebra over $F$, which is
isomorphic to $M_n(D)$ for some division algebra $D$(unique upto isomorphism) over $F$ of index $d$. Set $A_K=A_F\otimes_FK.$

Do we have similar commutative diagram in case of central simple algebras as above. If the answer is affirmative,suggest some reference regarding this..? Thank you.

Comment: I think your formulation is a bit clumsy. You first have to fix a (finite dimensional and central) division algebra $D_F$ over F (it is in general  not unique even up to isomorphisms) and then set $D_K = D_F \otimes_F K$. You may make your question more general by considering $A_F$ and $A_K = A\otimes_F K$, where $A_F$ is a central finite dimensional simple algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious idea to get a commutative square diagram,  where $GL(n,F)$ and $GL(n,K)$ are respectively replaced by $D_F^\times$ and $D_K^\times$,  is to use the Jacquet-Langlands transfer between representations of $D_F^\times$ (resp. $D_K^\times$) and square integrable representations of $GL(n,F)$ (resp. $GL(n,K)$) (cf. works of Deligne-Kazdhan-Vignéras, Rogawski, Badulescu). Of course this is not satisfactory for base change does not preserve square-integrability in general. But you could may be use the extension of the Jacquet-Langlands transfer to all representations, written by Badulescu.